# Adding attribute 'Traversal' to FindItem element for EWS using python

Tags: python, soap, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, suds

I am trying to search for emails in exchange 2007 through EWS using python, ewsclient and sud-ews, base on what I can found from the web, I have come out with the following code:

```
import ewsclient
import suds.client
import logging
from suds.transport.https import WindowsHttpAuthenticated

email = 'me@mycompany.com'
domain = 'webmail.mycompany.com'
username = r'mycompany\me'
password = 'Password'

transport = WindowsHttpAuthenticated(username=username,password=password)
client = suds.client.Client("https://%s/EWS/Services.wsdl" % domain,transport=transport,plugins=[ewsclient.AddService(),MyPlugin()])

mfrst = client.factory.create('ns1:ItemResponseShapeType')
mfrst.BaseShape = "IdOnly"

cvt = client.factory.create('ns1:ConstantValueType')
cvt._Value = "XXX"
cet = client.factory.create('ns1:ContainsExpressionType')
cet.Constant = cvt
cet._ContainmentComparison = "IgnoreCase"
cet._ContainmentMode = "Substring"
mrt = client.factory.create('ns1:RestrictionType')
mrt.SearchExpression = cet

fot = client.factory.create('ns1:FieldOrderType')
fot._Order = "Descending"
stor = client.factory.create('ns1:NonEmptyArrayOfFieldOrdersType')
stor.FieldOrder.append(fot)

mtdfit = client.factory.create('ns1:DistinguishedFolderIdType')
mtdfit._Id = "inbox"

gfrt = client.service.FindItem(mfrst,mrt,stor,mtdfit)
```

But what I got is the following error:
***WebFault: Server raised fault: 'The request failed schema validation: The required attribute 'Traversal' is missing.'***

In the readme file I can see that sud-ews **Added capability to specify attributes of method during call -- '_'-prefixed params**, but I can't figure out how to use it.